# How do I lower the rate of http requests triggered due to onChange for Material UI Slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, material-ui, onchange

How do I sort of buffer my requests?

Currently I am using Material UI's slider in my React project. I am using the onChange property to trigger a http post requests when I move along the slider. The code looks something like this.

```
<Slider
          onChange={handleChange}
          valueLabelFormat={valueLabelFormat}
          //   aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
          aria-labelledby="non-linear-slider"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          value={value}
          min={1}
          max={5}
          step={0.05}
        />
```

However, if you can imagine, the **onChange will be too frequent** and there will be **too many HTTP requests** being sent. This is definitely not recommended. I am also not intending to use onChangeCommitted as it is not my desired way of interaction.

So this is what I want to do:
IF I move along the slider (or onChange), onChange will continually update the value, but http requests will only be **triggered every 500ms** (with the latest value updated with onChange) . Rather than triggering a request for every onChange!
I have totally no idea how to achieve this..... setInterval or..? Not really sure.         Help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**
The answer is to use debounce (look at the answer below by **k.s.**)
However my use case is slightly different from the usual use cases. The function that I am using in my debounce requires inputs to it. I am using debounce inside my handleChange() function instead as I need the handleChange to set the value of my slider (so that it scrolls smoothly) and call debounce on the function inside that does the http calls.

```
<Slider
          onChange={handleChange}
          valueLabelFormat={valueLabelFormat}
          //   aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
          aria-labelledby="non-linear-slider"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          value={value}
          min={1}
          max={5}
          step={0.05}
        />
```

This is how my handleChange() looks like

```
const boostedLabel ="some label"

const handleChange = (_event, newValue) => {
    //Update value back to Slider
    setValue(newValue);

    const debouncedFunc = () => updateWeightValue(boostedLabel, newValue);
    debounce(debouncedFunc, 300, {leading:false, trailing:true});
  };
```

However this does not work! The slider moves but it does not seem like the debouncedFunc is triggered at all.

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting!  Can you please show your current react code, specifically the ````onChange```` function.  Thanks!

Comment: You can look into lodash debounce https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

Answer (score 5):

Your use case isn't notably different from other debounce use cases, you just aren't yet fully understanding how `debounce` should be used. Calling `debounce` does not invoke your function; instead it returns a debounced version of your function which can then be called as normal with however many parameters you need.

You should not be calling `debounce` in `handleChange`. You only want to call it once for the life of the element using it -- then you use the debounced version of the function (returned by `debounce`) within your `handleChange` function.

The simplest manner to do this is to create your debounced function at the top-level (entirely outside of your component). This isn't completely safe, however, if it is possible for you to have more than one element on the page for that type of component. If you had multiple elements sharing the same debounced function, it would be possible (though unlikely) for a very fast user to change more than one slider before the end of the delay (e.g. within 300 milliseconds) in which case the first element changed would not get saved to the back-end. If the debounced function is actually saving the current state of all the editable elements on the page (and not only the one triggering the change event), then calling debounce at the top-level is what you want.

To avoid the slight dangers of a top-level debounce, you can call debounce in your component in a manner that ensures only calling it once for your element. For the 3rd slider in my example below, I'm calling `debounce` in a [lazy state initializer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) and ignoring the setter that is also returned by `useState`. Then on each re-render, the same debounced function will be used. With slight changes, it would also be possible to leverage `useRef` instead of `useState` or `useCallback` or `useMemo` (though the guarantees of only calling debounce once per element are not as safe for `useCallback` and `useMemo` -- the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) states "You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.").

The example below shows 3 sliders (all sharing the same state). You can see that `callHttpRequest` just logs its arguments to the console. Each of the 3 sliders calls this in their `handleChange` functions in a different manner. The first is not debounced at all, so you can see many console logs as you move the slider. The second is debounced at the top-level, so you only see the console log when you stop moving the slider for at least 300 milliseconds. The third is debounced in the component within the [lazy initializer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) passed to `useState` and behaves the same as the second slider.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import VolumeDown from "@material-ui/icons/VolumeDown";
import VolumeUp from "@material-ui/icons/VolumeUp";
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 300
  }
});

const callHttpRequest = (eventSrcDesc, newValue) => {
  console.log({ eventSrcDesc, newValue });
};
const topLevelDebounceCallHttpRequest = debounce(callHttpRequest, 300, {
  leading: false,
  trailing: true
});

export default function ContinuousSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(30);

  const handleChangeNoDebounce = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    callHttpRequest("volume-no-debounce", newValue);
  };
  const handleChangeUsingTopLevelDebounce = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    topLevelDebounceCallHttpRequest("volume-top-level", newValue);
  };
  const [stateDebounceCallHttpRequest] = React.useState(() =>
    debounce(callHttpRequest, 300, {
      leading: false,
      trailing: true
    })
  );
  const handleChangeUsingStateDebounce = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    stateDebounceCallHttpRequest("volume-useState", newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="continuous-slider" gutterBottom>
        Volume (No Debounce)
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeDown />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChangeNoDebounce}
            aria-labelledby="continuous-slider"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeUp />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Typography id="continuous-slider-top-level-debounce" gutterBottom>
        Volume (Debounce called at top-level)
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeDown />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChangeUsingTopLevelDebounce}
            aria-labelledby="continuous-slider-top-level-debounce"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeUp />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Typography id="continuous-slider-useState-debounce" gutterBottom>
        Volume (Debounce called in useState lazy initializer)
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeDown />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChangeUsingStateDebounce}
            aria-labelledby="continuous-slider-useState-debounce"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeUp />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Debounce Slider onChange]

Here's a second sandbox that helps demonstrate the difference between the top-level debounce vs. the element-specific debounce: https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-slider-onchange-jimls?file=/demo.js. In this sandbox, the entire component is rendered twice and the delay is 3 seconds instead of 300 milliseconds. This provides plenty of time to move the two different sliders using the top-level debounce before the end of the delay and see that only the second produces a console log; whereas doing the same thing with the two sliders using the element-specific debounced function (managed via useState) produces one console log from each element.

Lodash debounce documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

Comment: This is exactly what I need and I believe it will be helpful to everyone who is searching for similar answers! The code demo is so helpful! Thanks

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have an extension to this. This works great, but as I drag along, there will be a few api calls being made, which is not ideal. How do I only call the api, say within 0.3s after i stop the sliding? In other words, when the slider is still 'active', dont trigger yet.

Comment: @Daryll That's already how this works. It only does the call after holding the slider still for at least 300 milliseconds. You can always bump up that value to 500 or 750 (whatever you want) if you want a longer wait before triggering the API call.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment. This is a perfect job for a debounce function. There are plenty of variations out there. Here's an example using [lodash/debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) function `onChange={debounce(handleChange)}`, it returns a function, which is good because the button is expecting a function reference. So on render your `handleChange` is called as the debounce function parameter and then you invoke it on the actual change event, and no matter how many `handleChange` events you will provide - only the last one will run.

Here's one of the implementations of a debounce function under the hood:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

taken from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) if you want to read a bit more about how it works.

**UPDATE**

The `debounce` function, returns a function, which you need to invoke.

```
const boostedLabel = "foo"

const handleChange = (_event, newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue);
  updateWeightValue(boostedLabel, newValue)
}
```

and still wrap with `debounce` when passing to the `onChange` prop, it will have all the arguments that are being passed to the `handleChange`

```
<Slider
          onChange={debounce(handleChange)}
          valueLabelFormat={valueLabelFormat}
          //   aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
          aria-labelledby="non-linear-slider"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          value={value}
          min={1}
          max={5}
          step={0.05}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what Im looking for. However I cant get it to work still as my implementation is slightly different. Look at my updated question above!